# How can I keep lines my levels of two days not joined like it is now?

Tags: pine-script

I am plotting camarilla levels using my own code. But the lines of two days are getting joined and it is looks very weird. Also the label text I want to be present at the beginning of each line. Right now it is on top of the first bar. How can I fix this?

```
//@version=4

study("Camarilla 1-6", overlay=true) 

[previous_day_high, previous_day_low, previous_day_close] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high[1], low[1], close[1]])

previous_day_range = previous_day_high - previous_day_low

// Resistances 
r4 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 2, 2)
r3 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 4, 2)
r2 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 6, 2)
r1 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 12, 2)

r5 = round(r4 + 1.168 * (r4 - r3), 2)
r6 = round((previous_day_high / previous_day_low) * previous_day_close, 2)

// Supports 
s4 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 2, 2)
s3 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 4, 2)
s2 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 6, 2)
s1 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 12, 2)

s5 = round(s4 - 1.168 * (s3 - s4), 2)
s6 = round(previous_day_close - (r6 - previous_day_close), 2)

// Plots
plot(r3 , title="H3: Go Short",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=2)
plot(r4 , title="H4: Long Breakout",  style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(r5 , title="H5: Target 1",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(r6 , title="H6: Target 2",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=2)

plot(s3 , title="L3: Go Long",        style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(s4 , title="L4: Short Breakout", style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=2)
plot(s5 , title="L5: Target 1",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=2)
plot(s6 , title="L6: Target 2",       style=plot.style_stepline, color=color.red,   linewidth=2)

// Labels
if (change(r3))
    label.new(bar_index, r3, text="H3: " + tostring(r3), style=label.style_none, textalign=text.align_left, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

if (change(r4))
    label.new(bar_index, r4, text="H4: " + tostring(r4), style=label.style_none)

if (change(r5))
    label.new(bar_index, r5, text="H5: " + tostring(r5), style=label.style_none)

if (change(r6))
    label.new(bar_index, r6, text="H6: " + tostring(r6), style=label.style_none)
```

It looks like now:

[image]

But I want it to looks like as this example code screenshot looks like https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#pivot-points-standard. What things I need to change?

I was trying the options `textalign=text.align_left, yloc=yloc.abovebar`, but they are not the solution of my problem here. I kept them as it is there for now, that's why you see it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joined lines can be fixed like this.

```
//@version=4

study("Camarilla 1-6", overlay=true) 

[previous_day_high, previous_day_low, previous_day_close] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high[1], low[1], close[1]])

previous_day_range = previous_day_high - previous_day_low

// Resistances 
r4 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 2, 2)
r3 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 4, 2)
r2 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 6, 2)
r1 = round(previous_day_close + (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 12, 2)

r5 = round(r4 + 1.168 * (r4 - r3), 2)
r6 = round((previous_day_high / previous_day_low) * previous_day_close, 2)

// Supports 
s4 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 2, 2)
s3 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 4, 2)
s2 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 6, 2)
s1 = round(previous_day_close - (previous_day_range) * 1.1 / 12, 2)

s5 = round(s4 - 1.168 * (s3 - s4), 2)
s6 = round(previous_day_close - (r6 - previous_day_close), 2)

// Plots
plot(r3 , title="H3: Go Short",       style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(r3)?na:color.red,   linewidth=2)
plot(r4 , title="H4: Long Breakout",  style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(r4)?na:color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(r5 , title="H5: Target 1",       style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(r5)?na:color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(r6 , title="H6: Target 2",       style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(r6)?na:color.green, linewidth=2)

plot(s3 , title="L3: Go Long",        style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(s3)?na:color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(s4 , title="L4: Short Breakout", style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(s4)?na:color.red,   linewidth=2)
plot(s5 , title="L5: Target 1",       style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(s5)?na:color.red,   linewidth=2)
plot(s6 , title="L6: Target 2",       style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(s6)?na:color.red,   linewidth=2)

// Labels
if (change(r3))
    label.new(bar_index, r3, text="H3: " + tostring(r3), style=label.style_none, textalign=text.align_left, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

if (change(r4))
    label.new(bar_index, r4, text="H4: " + tostring(r4), style=label.style_none)

if (change(r5))
    label.new(bar_index, r5, text="H5: " + tostring(r5), style=label.style_none)

if (change(r6))
    label.new(bar_index, r6, text="H6: " + tostring(r6), style=label.style_none)
```

Which yields

[image: Example]

Not sure what you mean by

> *Also the label text I want to be present at the beginning of each line.*
> *Right now it is on top of the first bar.*

**Edit 1** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68067840/how-can-i-keep-lines-my-levels-of-two-days-not-joined-like-it-is-now/68071916?noredirect=1#comment120323902_68071916)

The `?:` is a [ternary conditional operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D).
This is a short-hand form of an `if-then-else` syntax.

This statement

```
color=change(s3)?na:color.green
```

Is identical to

```
if change(s3)
    color := na
else
    color := color.green
```

What it does, is to set the color of the line to `na` (=no color) when the value changes.

Normally, when a plot line changes value, Pine draws a connecting line from the old to the new value, in the same color as the line, as can be seen in this example in yellow:

[image: Example]

The code for that 'connecting' yellow line is

```
plot(s6 , title="L6: Target 2",       style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.yellow)
```

So, by setting the color to `na` (=no color) when the value changes, the connecting line becomes invisible, as can be seen with the other (non-yellow) lines.

When we would substitute `na` with another color, then the connecting lines would show up as that color instead of invisible.

For example, if we change the code for `s4` to show color `white` instead of `na`:

```
plot(s4 , title="L4: Short Breakout", style=plot.style_linebr, color=change(s4)?color.white:color.red,   linewidth=2)
```

That would make the connecting lines `white` instead of invisible.

[image: Example]

Comment: Your change I see `color=change(s3)?na:color.green`. Can you explain what it is doing? I mean how it solved ?

Comment: Added Edit 1 section with explanation and example screenshots.